# Using Tenor API in Python for printing gifs

Tags: python

So, I am trying to print out gifs by using Tenor API.
I want it to only print one gif link but it prints out everything any Idea how to fix this?
Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf084.png

Comment: For any code, copy it into the question. Highlight it. Then there should be a button that looks like two chains linked together, click it and it will format any text to code. You can do that with edit.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I can not tell you the exact problem you are having, I replicated your code and used the official [API Docs here](https://tenor.com/gifapi/documentation#endpoints-suggestions)

From what I can tell, this is one GIF just in a lot of different formats. 
You can filter them like so:

```
print(top_8gifs['weburl'])
```

or

```
print(top_8gifs['results'][0])
```

EDIT: Looking at your .png (please embed it as code in the future) this should work for you, if you want the url:

```
print(top_8gifs[0]['url'])
```

- A Python dict you can select using the key (like gifs['weburl'])
- A Python list you have to select by index so gifs[0]

Using these techniques you can gather the data you need from that output.

Comment: Thanks, dude that helped me a lot really appreciate it!

Comment: @ZakeDe no problem :) I'd be super happy if you marked my answer as the solution, or at least upvote it, thanks!